# Trouble with Error: Column `group` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I addressed this question in a previous post but because I did not get a satisfactory answer I've tried the following.

I've a dataset with 80-second intervals that I would like to transform into 240-second intervals. Here's a sample of it:

```
> head(dataraw)
     GMT_DATE GMT_TIME ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z Vigilance Head-up Grazing Browsing Moving
1: 06/17/2018 09:36:00         78         38         87         0      35       0       35      1
2: 06/17/2018 09:37:20         18         17         25         0      46       0        0     26
3: 06/17/2018 09:38:40          7          4          8         0      69       0        0      0
4: 06/17/2018 09:40:00          4          0          4         0      70       0        0      0
5: 06/17/2018 09:41:20         11          8         14         0      29       0        0     11
6: 06/17/2018 09:42:40         27         20         34         0       0      58        0      0
   Grooming Resting Fleeing Unknown End Total
1:        4       0       0       5   0    80
2:        8       0       0       0   0    80
3:        5       0       0       6   0    80
4:       10       0       0       0   0    80
5:       15       0       0      25   0    80
6:       10       0       0      12   0    80
```

However, note that some intervals are 160-seconds (rows `5` to `6`), which I'm still not sure how to address that issue:

```
> head(dataraw[c(3626:3632),])
     GMT_DATE GMT_TIME ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z Vigilance Head-up Grazing Browsing Moving
1: 06/20/2018 18:09:20          0          0          0         0       0       0        0      0
2: 06/20/2018 18:10:40          0          0          0         0       0       0        0      0
3: 06/20/2018 18:12:00          1          0          1         0       0       0        0      0
4: 06/20/2018 18:13:20          0          0          0         0       0       0        0      0
5: 06/20/2018 18:14:40          0          0          0         0       0       0        0      0
6: 06/20/2018 18:17:20          4          0          4         0       0       0        0      0
   Grooming Resting Fleeing Unknown End Total
1:        0       0       0       0  80    80
2:        0       0       0       0  80    80
3:        0       0       0       0  80    80
4:        0       0       0       0  80    80
5:        0       0       0       0  80    80
6:        0       0       0       0  80    80
```

Anyways, I tried the script below for which I'm getting the error:

```
> library(dplyr)
> datarawnew<-dataraw %>%
+   tidyr::unite(datetime, GMT_DATE, GMT_TIME, sep = " ") %>%
+   mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"), 
+          row = 1) %>%
+   group_by(group = cut(datetime, breaks = "4 mins")) %>%
+   summarise_at(-1, sum) %>%
+   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("ACTIVITY")), ~. /row) %>%
+   ungroup() %>%
+   select(-row)
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `group` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable
```

Could anybody please let me know what am I doing wrong? I can upload a `dput()` sample below:

```
> dput(dataraw[c(1:250),])
structure(list(GMT_DATE = c("06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018"), GMT_TIME = c("09:36:00", "09:37:20", 
"09:38:40", "09:40:00", "09:41:20", "09:42:40", "09:44:00", "09:45:20", 
"09:46:40", "09:48:00", "09:49:20", "09:50:40", "09:52:00", "09:53:20", 
"09:54:40", "09:56:00", "09:57:20", "09:58:40", "10:00:00", "10:01:20", 
"10:02:40", "10:04:00", "10:05:20", "10:06:40", "10:08:00", "10:09:20", 
"10:10:40", "10:12:00", "10:13:20", "10:14:40", "10:16:00", "10:17:20", 
"10:18:40", "10:20:00", "10:21:20", "10:22:40", "10:24:00", "10:25:20", 
"10:26:40", "10:28:00", "10:29:20", "10:30:40", "10:32:00", "10:33:20", 
"10:34:40", "10:36:00", "10:37:20", "10:38:40", "10:40:00", "10:41:20", 
"10:42:40", "10:44:00", "10:45:20", "10:46:40", "10:48:00", "10:49:20", 
"10:50:40", "10:52:00", "10:53:20", "10:54:40", "10:56:00", "10:57:20", 
"10:58:40", "11:00:00", "11:01:20", "11:02:40", "11:04:00", "11:05:20", 
"11:06:40", "11:08:00", "11:09:20", "11:10:40", "11:12:00", "11:13:20", 
"11:14:40", "11:16:00", "11:17:20", "11:18:40", "11:20:00", "11:21:20", 
"11:22:40", "11:24:00", "11:25:20", "11:26:40", "11:28:00", "11:29:20", 
"11:30:40", "11:32:00", "11:33:20", "11:34:40", "11:36:00", "11:37:20", 
"11:38:40", "11:40:00", "11:41:20", "11:42:40", "11:44:00", "11:45:20", 
"11:46:40", "11:48:00", "11:49:20", "11:50:40", "11:52:00", "11:53:20", 
"11:54:40", "11:56:00", "11:57:20", "11:58:40", "12:00:00", "12:01:20", 
"12:02:40", "12:04:00", "12:05:20", "12:06:40", "12:08:00", "12:09:20", 
"12:10:40", "12:12:00", "12:13:20", "12:14:40", "12:16:00", "12:17:20", 
"12:18:40", "12:20:00", "12:21:20", "12:22:40", "12:24:00", "12:25:20", 
"12:26:40", "12:28:00", "12:29:20", "12:30:40", "12:32:00", "12:33:20", 
"12:34:40", "12:36:00", "12:37:20", "12:38:40", "12:40:00", "12:41:20", 
"12:42:40", "12:44:00", "12:45:20", "12:46:40", "12:48:00", "12:49:20", 
"12:50:40", "12:52:00", "12:53:20", "12:54:40", "12:56:00", "12:57:20", 
"12:58:40", "13:00:00", "13:01:20", "13:02:40", "13:04:00", "13:05:20", 
"13:06:40", "13:08:00", "13:09:20", "13:10:40", "13:12:00", "13:13:20", 
"13:14:40", "13:16:00", "13:17:20", "13:18:40", "13:20:00", "13:21:20", 
"13:22:40", "13:24:00", "13:25:20", "13:26:40", "13:28:00", "13:29:20", 
"13:30:40", "13:32:00", "13:33:20", "13:34:40", "13:36:00", "13:37:20", 
"13:38:40", "13:40:00", "13:41:20", "13:42:40", "13:44:00", "13:45:20", 
"13:46:40", "13:48:00", "13:49:20", "13:50:40", "13:52:00", "13:53:20", 
"13:54:40", "13:56:00", "13:57:20", "13:58:40", "14:00:00", "14:01:20", 
"14:02:40", "14:04:00", "14:05:20", "14:06:40", "14:08:00", "14:09:20", 
"14:10:40", "14:12:00", "14:13:20", "14:14:40", "14:16:00", "14:17:20", 
"14:18:40", "14:20:00", "14:21:20", "14:22:40", "14:24:00", "14:25:20", 
"14:26:40", "14:28:00", "14:29:20", "14:30:40", "14:32:00", "14:33:20", 
"14:34:40", "14:36:00", "14:37:20", "14:38:40", "14:40:00", "14:41:20", 
"14:42:40", "14:44:00", "14:45:20", "14:46:40", "14:48:00", "14:49:20", 
"14:50:40", "14:52:00", "14:53:20", "14:54:40", "14:56:00", "14:57:20", 
"14:58:40", "15:00:00", "15:01:20", "15:02:40", "15:04:00", "15:05:20", 
"15:06:40", "15:08:00"), ACTIVITY_X = c(78L, 18L, 7L, 4L, 11L, 
27L, 19L, 23L, 21L, 19L, 24L, 25L, 13L, 15L, 31L, 52L, 71L, 141L, 
103L, 59L, 43L, 85L, 129L, 81L, 106L, 86L, 129L, 82L, 67L, 145L, 
120L, 95L, 97L, 139L, 160L, 147L, 83L, 102L, 84L, 90L, 92L, 84L, 
95L, 121L, 84L, 58L, 72L, 72L, 52L, 65L, 83L, 57L, 61L, 72L, 
82L, 88L, 116L, 125L, 126L, 79L, 49L, 51L, 77L, 84L, 99L, 96L, 
90L, 72L, 74L, 61L, 86L, 71L, 52L, 24L, 52L, 55L, 53L, 37L, 49L, 
57L, 58L, 59L, 45L, 53L, 72L, 49L, 60L, 77L, 79L, 93L, 110L, 
76L, 108L, 63L, 78L, 78L, 83L, 66L, 40L, 30L, 75L, 29L, 30L, 
37L, 39L, 38L, 41L, 48L, 16L, 58L, 75L, 81L, 85L, 64L, 51L, 31L, 
33L, 76L, 65L, 76L, 63L, 75L, 59L, 60L, 44L, 54L, 51L, 68L, 75L, 
93L, 82L, 83L, 86L, 79L, 67L, 59L, 94L, 75L, 47L, 28L, 66L, 58L, 
53L, 34L, 31L, 40L, 35L, 45L, 33L, 47L, 42L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 21L, 
26L, 30L, 47L, 34L, 28L, 31L, 48L, 33L, 45L, 33L, 41L, 40L, 44L, 
53L, 25L, 38L, 27L, 44L, 96L, 42L, 55L, 49L, 44L, 46L, 45L, 51L, 
58L, 36L, 27L, 35L, 53L, 44L, 44L, 60L, 29L, 36L, 38L, 39L, 36L, 
37L, 32L, 23L, 35L, 46L, 58L, 63L, 67L, 166L, 123L, 44L, 53L, 
68L, 43L, 48L, 61L, 48L, 65L, 54L, 69L, 67L, 62L, 51L, 49L, 41L, 
42L, 39L, 58L, 40L, 52L, 46L, 38L, 48L, 28L, 32L, 48L, 42L, 39L, 
90L, 108L, 44L, 40L, 22L, 38L, 22L, 45L, 32L, 27L, 23L, 13L, 
53L, 32L, 45L, 62L, 55L, 48L), ACTIVITY_Y = c(38L, 17L, 4L, 0L, 
8L, 20L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 13L, 16L, 23L, 4L, 8L, 21L, 46L, 105L, 
133L, 131L, 64L, 34L, 76L, 94L, 51L, 80L, 58L, 69L, 47L, 57L, 
108L, 102L, 80L, 71L, 127L, 135L, 114L, 116L, 131L, 100L, 77L, 
131L, 127L, 72L, 114L, 87L, 54L, 97L, 88L, 43L, 45L, 84L, 62L, 
91L, 87L, 114L, 94L, 76L, 97L, 81L, 155L, 49L, 72L, 89L, 125L, 
113L, 63L, 66L, 78L, 82L, 44L, 96L, 53L, 47L, 20L, 35L, 42L, 
46L, 31L, 38L, 45L, 37L, 42L, 34L, 28L, 86L, 55L, 42L, 62L, 63L, 
113L, 95L, 131L, 215L, 79L, 90L, 43L, 42L, 54L, 47L, 24L, 96L, 
31L, 34L, 24L, 46L, 36L, 42L, 59L, 13L, 73L, 73L, 94L, 109L, 
89L, 28L, 26L, 38L, 105L, 60L, 129L, 48L, 59L, 81L, 67L, 51L, 
36L, 81L, 154L, 74L, 80L, 81L, 79L, 83L, 57L, 47L, 62L, 75L, 
57L, 43L, 33L, 66L, 58L, 81L, 20L, 16L, 27L, 25L, 34L, 15L, 30L, 
31L, 9L, 24L, 18L, 19L, 22L, 21L, 63L, 33L, 15L, 15L, 43L, 25L, 
28L, 23L, 30L, 21L, 24L, 40L, 18L, 35L, 16L, 37L, 120L, 27L, 
45L, 42L, 33L, 45L, 36L, 32L, 36L, 35L, 22L, 24L, 31L, 38L, 32L, 
46L, 21L, 22L, 20L, 22L, 21L, 25L, 22L, 18L, 22L, 26L, 43L, 83L, 
103L, 239L, 165L, 49L, 47L, 41L, 27L, 33L, 36L, 26L, 46L, 25L, 
36L, 55L, 42L, 41L, 39L, 16L, 25L, 22L, 43L, 28L, 36L, 30L, 19L, 
19L, 13L, 16L, 41L, 37L, 117L, 132L, 45L, 45L, 23L, 19L, 29L, 
19L, 55L, 43L, 38L, 15L, 11L, 52L, 28L, 32L, 45L, 71L, 53L), 
    ACTIVITY_Z = c(87L, 25L, 8L, 4L, 14L, 34L, 22L, 25L, 22L, 
    23L, 29L, 34L, 14L, 17L, 37L, 69L, 127L, 194L, 167L, 87L, 
    55L, 114L, 160L, 96L, 133L, 104L, 146L, 95L, 88L, 181L, 157L, 
    124L, 120L, 188L, 209L, 186L, 143L, 166L, 131L, 118L, 160L, 
    152L, 119L, 166L, 121L, 79L, 121L, 114L, 67L, 79L, 118L, 
    84L, 110L, 113L, 140L, 129L, 139L, 158L, 150L, 174L, 69L, 
    88L, 118L, 151L, 150L, 115L, 112L, 106L, 110L, 75L, 129L, 
    89L, 70L, 31L, 63L, 69L, 70L, 48L, 62L, 73L, 69L, 72L, 56L, 
    60L, 112L, 74L, 73L, 99L, 101L, 146L, 145L, 151L, 241L, 101L, 
    119L, 89L, 93L, 85L, 62L, 38L, 122L, 42L, 45L, 44L, 60L, 
    52L, 59L, 76L, 21L, 93L, 105L, 124L, 138L, 110L, 58L, 40L, 
    50L, 130L, 88L, 150L, 79L, 95L, 100L, 90L, 67L, 65L, 96L, 
    168L, 105L, 123L, 115L, 115L, 120L, 97L, 82L, 86L, 120L, 
    94L, 64L, 43L, 93L, 82L, 97L, 39L, 35L, 48L, 43L, 56L, 36L, 
    56L, 52L, 26L, 35L, 32L, 28L, 34L, 37L, 79L, 47L, 32L, 34L, 
    64L, 41L, 53L, 40L, 51L, 45L, 50L, 66L, 31L, 52L, 31L, 57L, 
    154L, 50L, 71L, 65L, 55L, 64L, 58L, 60L, 68L, 50L, 35L, 42L, 
    61L, 58L, 54L, 76L, 36L, 42L, 43L, 45L, 42L, 45L, 39L, 29L, 
    41L, 53L, 72L, 104L, 123L, 291L, 206L, 66L, 71L, 79L, 51L, 
    58L, 71L, 55L, 80L, 60L, 78L, 87L, 75L, 65L, 63L, 44L, 49L, 
    45L, 72L, 49L, 63L, 55L, 42L, 52L, 31L, 36L, 63L, 56L, 123L, 
    160L, 117L, 63L, 46L, 29L, 48L, 29L, 71L, 54L, 47L, 27L, 
    17L, 74L, 43L, 55L, 77L, 90L, 72L), Vigilance = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    7L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Head-up` = c(35L, 46L, 
    69L, 70L, 29L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 80L, 
    72L, 73L, 62L, 73L, 64L, 38L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 5L, 
    0L, 39L, 22L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    58L, 80L, 53L, 31L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 41L, 76L, 63L, 12L, 63L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 80L
    ), Grazing = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 58L, 66L, 72L, 67L, 38L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 63L, 0L, 
    9L, 75L, 80L, 68L, 69L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Browsing = c(35L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 21L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Moving = c(1L, 26L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    4L, 7L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 17L, 7L, 5L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Grooming = c(4L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 
    10L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 
    7L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Resting = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fleeing = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Unknown = c(5L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 25L, 12L, 0L, 
    7L, 13L, 28L, 49L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 
    38L, 13L, 36L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 52L, 23L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 42L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 11L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 61L, 
    12L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), End = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 31L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 37L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 58L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 69L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 39L, 0L
    ), Total = c(80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L)), row.names = c(NA, -250L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002631ef0>)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code you posted:

```r
> dataraw %>%
+   tidyr::unite(datetime, GMT_DATE, GMT_TIME, sep = " ") %>%
+   mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"), 
+          row = 1) %>%
+   group_by(group = cut(datetime, breaks = "4 mins")) %>%
+   summarise_at(-1, sum) %>%
+   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("ACTIVITY")), ~. /row) %>%
+   ungroup() %>%
+   select(-row)
```

never assigned this to a new data frame or over wrote the original data. I.e., you are missing:

```r
newdataraw <- dataraw %>% ...
```

So, try running, e.g.,

```r
newdataraw <- dataraw  %>%
  tidyr::unite(datetime, GMT_DATE, GMT_TIME, sep = " ") %>%
   mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"), 
          row = 1) %>%
   group_by(group = cut(datetime, breaks = "4 mins")) %>%
   summarise_at(-1, sum) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("ACTIVITY")), ~. /row) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(-row)
```

If that solves it, then you just have the typo, as mentioned above..

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've update my question with a new script. Assigning a new dataframe doesn't change the outcome of the script.

Comment: If you could post a reproducible example of dataraw, then you might get an answer pretty quickly. Otherwise I don't see anything obvious here.

Comment: There's a `dput()` sample in the main post. I guess that's everything I can provide?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the dput example, but I don't use dput so it may be something obvious. Apologies/